# Why is one_of() called that?

Tags: r, naming

Why is `dplyr::one_of()` called that? All the other `select_helpers` names make sense to me, so I'm wondering if there's an aspect of `one_of()` that I don't understand.

My understanding of `one_of()` is that it just lets you select variables using a character vector of their names instead of putting their names into the `select()` call, but then you get all of the variables whose names are in the vector, not just **one of** them. Is that wrong, and if it's correct, where does the name `one_of()` come from?

Comment: I think the only persons that can answer to that are the developers of `dplyr`. Try e-mailing `maintainer("dplyr")`.

Comment: +1. Great question. Was looking for `one_of` to pass a character vector to functions in the `recipes` package only to ignore/overlook it because the name suggests that it returns only one... might have been perhaps more intuitive to call `one_of` something like `from_names`...

Comment: Seems like it would be better named `is_one_of()`, to match the predicate-style naming of `starts_with()`, `contains()`, `matches()`, etc.

Answer (score 34):

`one_of` allows for guessing or subset-matching

Let's say I know in general my column names will come from `c("mpg","cyl","garbage")` but I don't know which columns will be present because of interactivity/reactivity

```
mtcars %>% select(one_of(c("mpg","cyl","garbage")))
```

evaluates but provides a message

```
Warning message:
Unknown variables: `garbage`
```

In contrast

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, garbage)
```

does not evaluate and gives the error

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
  object 'garbage' not found
```

Answer (score 22):

The way I think about it is that `select()` eventually evaluates to a logical vector. So if you use `starts_with` it goes through the variables in the dataframe and asks whether the variable name starts with the right set of characters. `one_of` does the same thing but asks whether the variable name is one of the names listed in the character vector. But as they say, naming things is hard!

Comment: I think you nailed it. The `tidyverse` packages often make use of synonyms of names of base R functions, `one_of` should be thought as a synonym of `%in%` and we check if each colname is "one of" the given options, then everything makes sense. Still not a fan of the name though :).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for its name seems to be that it allows you to look for, at least, one of the variables that are contained in the vector.

For example:

`select(flights, dep, arr_delay, sched_dep_time)` won't work because the variable "dep" does not exits. It will produce no result.

`select(flights, one_of(c("dep", "arr_delay", "sched_dep_time")))` will work, even due the variable "dep" does not exist. In this case, "arr_delay" and "sched_dep_time" will be shown.

The helper should be read as: at least `one_of()` the variables will be shown :)